# Momentum transfer from flowing fluid to solid object

Tags: fluid-dynamics, momentum

In collisions’ physics, in particular imperfect elastic collision, the transfer of momentum between a solid body to another, can be described with the formula:

$$p_{1i} + p_{2i} = p_{1f} + p_{2f}$$

with:

$$p_{1f} = m_1 \left( \left[\frac{m_1-m_2}{m_1+m_2}v_{1i}\right] + \left[\frac{2m_2}{m_1+m_2}v_{2i}\right] \right)$$

$$p_{2f} = m_2 \left( \left[\frac{2m_1}{m_1+m_2}v_{1i} \right]+ \left[\frac{m_2-m_1}{m_1+m_2} v_{2i} \right] \right)$$

However, how can this formula be adapted to cases where a solid body is struck by a jet of flowing fluid?

As an example, let’s visualize a rigid ball ($m_2 = 1$ kg ; $v_{2i} = 0$ m/s) laying on a perfectly horizontal plane of frictionless material, that is hit center-mass by a flux of air (dot-m = $0.024$ kg/s; $v_{1i} = 10$ m/s) parallel to the plane, at such a distance the loss in pressure of the jet is negligible. How can I mathematically simulate the transfer of momentum from flow to ball?

Answer (score 4):

You can start your analysis by looking at a volume of the jet at time $t=0$. After some time $\Delta t$, the volume has moved a distance of $v\Delta t$ so that the volume entering the region has volume of,
$$\text{vol}=\text{area}\times\text{dist}=A\times v\Delta t$$
and the mass is still density times volume, yielding,
$$m=\rho V=\rho Av\Delta t.$$
This also means that the time rate of change of the mass is,
$$\dot{m}=\rho Av.$$
Lastly, we get the momentum to be the mass times the fluid velocity,
$$p=mv=\rho Av^2\Delta t=\dot{m}v\Delta t.$$
So in order to do the momentum conservation of the jet & ball, you would also need to define the time in which the jet is in contact with the ball. It probably would be something small, like millisecond scale at most, but you might want to check around for a more accurate number.

Comment: I think this would work since conservation of momentum depends on interval.

Comment: I see, I had the idea but I was unsure of how accurate it would be to reality.

Comment: _"rate of change of the mass"_, you mean, mass flow rate.

Comment: @PasserBy a distinction without a difference; both phrases mean the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

1. First we have to apply conservation law, which states that:
   $$m_1\vec{u}_1+m_2\vec{u}_1=m_1\vec{v}_1+m_2\vec{v}_2$$
   Coefficient of restitution can be written as: $$e(\vec{u}_2-\vec{u}_1)=-(\vec{v}_2-\vec{v}_1)$$
   $$\vec{v}_2=\vec{v}_1-e(\vec{u}_2-\vec{u}_1)$$
   This can be substituted into the first equation to get:
   $$\vec{v}_1=\frac{\vec{u}_1(m_1-m_2e)}{m_1+m_2}+\frac{(1+e)m_2\vec{u}_2}{m_1+m_2}$$
   $$\vec{v}_2=\frac{\vec{u}_2(m_2-m_1e)}{m_1+m_2}+\frac{(1+e)m_1\vec{u}_1}{m_1+m_2}$$
   This can be used to find out the velocities of two bodies after change in momentum.
2. When air strikes the ball it will apply force and the ball will gain velocity. If the force acting is constant, then change in velocity can be found out by equations of motion.

Comment: But how can I determine the mass m1 if I have a flow of air instead of a rigid object? Or maybe I’m mistaken your intent, and you meant m1 as being the mass flow rate?

Comment: @Riccardo Zanardi. I am not completely sure this can be used to simulate the given e.g. In collisions, It is assumed that forces acts like impulse. So velocity after collision acquires a static value. If we were to consider an constant force, then it would be better to use newton's 2nd law seperately on two bodies.